# bash script: How to append characters at the end of a string efficiently (O(1))

Tags: string, performance, bash, append

Simple problem: I have an array A of n entries each one containing one character. I want
to create the corresponding string S from this array in an efficient way, i.e. in O(n) time, without using external commands, just bash code and bash builtins.

This obvious way...

```
func_slow ()
{ 
 local numel=${#A[*]}
 for ((i=0; i < numel ; i++))
 do
    S=${S}${A[$i]}   
 done
}
```

is not efficient with bash. It's O(n^2) time because the "append" operation S=${S}${A[$i]}
doesn't take O(1) time worst case (or even O(1) time amortized which would be enough to guarantee an overall O(n) time). It takes O(#S) each time (clearly it generates the new  string S by copying both ${S} and ${A[$i]}). 
The only way I can find to solve this in O(n) time (without external commands) is by defining this function

```
func_fast ()
{
 local numel=${#A[*]}
 for ((i=0; i < numel ; i++))
 do
    echo -n "${A[$i]}"
 done
}
```

and then using it like this

```
S=`func_fast`
```

This takes O(n) time and it just uses bash code and bash builtins. Implementing (within an interpreter of a language) strings with an efficient append operator (one that would allow func_slow to run in O(n) time) while still retaining O(1) time direct access of each position of a string is pretty simple from an algorithmic point of view, I was wondering if I'm missing some special efficient bash string operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use array merging with IFS:

```
IFS= eval 'S="${A[*]}"'
```

Also if you're going to append a string to a variable, just use this form:

```
S+="another"
```

Another fast way is to use printf:

```
printf -v S '%s' "${A[@]}"
```

Adding some benchmarks. With an array having 100000 integral elements:

```
time printf -v X '%s' "${A[@]}"

real    0m0.481s
user    0m0.474s
sys     0m0.004s

time IFS= eval 'X="${A[*]}"'

real    0m0.107s
user    0m0.106s
sys     0m0.000s

X=''; L=${#A[@]}; time for (( I = 0; I < L; ++I )); do X+=${A[I]}; done

real    0m24.469s
user    0m24.351s
sys     0m0.074s
```

Comment: So I guess no efficient append operator (the += seems to be just as slow as doing S=${S}${A[$i]}). Anyway the other two are good answers (the IFS one looks rather exotic to me :) )

Comment: @terr At least with the IFS method, you could choose the separator you like :) By the way using eval is optional but to make it effective IFS should be set before the line is parsed. So you can do it as well like `IFS=; X="${A[*]}"`. But that would permanently set IFS, so you have to set it back to its default to not affect other commands: `IFS=$' \t\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an in-place edit, adding text to the end, you can do this:

```
sed -ie 's/$/WHATEVER/g' FILENAME
```

Or, to add text to the beginning:

```
sed -ie 's/^/WHATEVER/g' FILENAME
```

Special characters will have to be escaped via `\`. A regex cheat sheet is your best friend.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the computational complexity, but this works:

```
t=${A[@]}
S=${t// /}
```

Comment: Mmmh..it doesn't work for me. So the S=${t// /} deletes spaces from t (it substitutes  them with nothing), right? Not sure what  ${A[@]} is...that notation for me works only if A is already a string.

Comment: `${A[@]}` is essentially the same as `${A[*]}`, differing only when they are in double quotes.  When double quoted, * uses the first character of IFS as the separator.